# Differential of a multiplication map

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $G$ be a group, and let $e \in G$ be the unit. Suppose that $G$ has the structure of a manifold so that the multiplication map $m: G \times G \rightarrow G$ is smooth.

Now show that $d_{(e,e)} m(X,Y) = X + Y$, where $d_{(e,e)}m: T_e G \oplus T_e G = T_eG$.
(Hint:$d_{(e,e)}m(X,Y)=d_{(e,e)}(X,0)+d_{(e,e)}(0,Y)$

So $d_{(e,e)}(X,0)=X$ and $d_{(e,e)}(0,Y)=Y$ would give the desired result and my best guess would be that this follows from the smoothness of the map m, I just do not see how this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\gamma\colon(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to G$ is a smooth curve so that $\gamma(0)=e$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0)=X$.  Then define $\tilde{\gamma}\colon(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to G\times G$ by $\tilde{\gamma}(t)=(\gamma(t),e)$.  Notice that $\dot{\tilde{\gamma}}(0)=(\dot{\gamma}(0),0)=(X,0)$.  So
\begin{equation}
dm_{(e,e)}(X,0) = \frac{d}{dt}((m\circ\tilde{\gamma})(t)) = \frac{d}{dt}(\gamma(t)\cdot e) = \frac{d}{dt}(\gamma(t)) = X.
\end{equation}
A similar trick will show that $dm_{(e,e)}(0,Y)=Y$.